# Removing periods at the end of line in moderncv

Tags: itemize

How can I remove the two periods after the words First and Second in `\cvitem`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{YOLO}{UOLO}
\title{curriculum vitae}                              
\address{YOLO}
\phone[mobile]{000-0-000-000}                   

\email{YOLO@YOLO.com}                           

\begin{document}

%-----       resume       -------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle

\section{Professional Experience}
\cvitem{Something}{Something else}


\section{Customer Service}
 \cventry{1958--1960}{First}{}{}{}{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item
\end{itemize}}{}{}
\cventry{1945--1958}{Second}{}{}{}{
\begin{itemize} 
    \item item
 \end{itemize}}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The punctuation is provided by the command `\cventry` as defined in `moderncvbodyi.sty`.  You can redefine the `\cventry` simply removing the fullstop from the definition by

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%                             %Fullstop removed
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}


% personal data
\name{YOLO}{UOLO}
\title{curriculum vitae}
\address{YOLO}
\phone[mobile]{000-0-000-000}

\email{YOLO@YOLO.com}

\begin{document}

%-----       resume       -------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle

\section{Professional Experience}
\cvitem{Something}{Something else}


\section{Customer Service}
 \cventry{1958--1960}{First}{}{}{}{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item
\end{itemize}}{}{}
\cventry{1945--1958}{Second}{}{}{}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item item
 \end{itemize}}{}{}
\end{document}
```